# why does my code approximate some numbers?

Tags: javascript, math

I made a copy of Math.abs(), using the two's complement to find the opposite of a number. The thing is that it's approximating some numbers, especially the ones with 1 to 3 decimal points.

```
function abs(x: number) {
  return x & (1 << 63) ? ~x + 1 : x;
}
```

So it's checking the sign bit of the number, and if it is set, find the opposite. 
It's approximating -214.45 to 214, or like -2745.892 to 2745, why is that?

Comment: Decimal points? [Bitwise operators](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#bitwise_operators) only work for 32-bit integers or BigInts (almost all of them), none of which are fractional.

Comment: Bear in mind that the representation of floating point numbers is somewhat different than integers; bitwise operations which work on integers will have a different effect on floats. I would try to write the function by using arithmetic operations instead of bit operations.